# Need to display image in ASPX page that has long url

Tags: javascript, asp.net, post, url-rewriting, imageurl

Scenario: Within ASP.NET site, I have an ASPX page where within OnLoad event, I set the imageUrl for one of the image controls. This URL value comes from an external source and the image is not getting displayed and I found out it is because the URL is too long.

How to display images of longer URLs? Should I use POST with javascript or any other options to achieve? The values within the URL are crucial and I can't loose some of the parameters.

Please suggest.

Code in OnLoad event is something below.

```
        Image pImage = new Image();

        pImage.ImageUrl = imageFile; // imageFile is the one having long URL.
```

Update 1: If I am able to achieve the POST in OnLoad, then I think image will get displayed. Please suggest how to acheve this in OnLoad.

Update 2 : The actual URL is below.

http://example.com/is/m//company1/Rec-Sc-105-QL2?setAttr.safe={visible=false}&setAttr.insertedTextPlaceholder={visible=false}&setElement.height_weight=%253Ccontent%253E%253Cdiv%2520columnCount%253D%25221%2522%2520columnGap%253D%252218%2522%2520fontFamily%253D%2522Comic%2520Sans%2520MS%2522%2520textAlign%253D%2522left%2522%2520s7%253AcolorName%253D%2522100%2525%2520Black%2522%2520s7%253Acolorspace%253D%2522defined%2522%2520s7%253AcolorValue%253D%2522%2523FF%2522%253E%253Cp%253E%253Cspan%253EHeight%2520%2526amp%253B%2520Weight%253C/span%253E%253C/p%253E%253C/div%253E%253C/content%253E&setAttr.height_weight=%7Bheight=17.825466666666667%2526visible=true%2526rotation=0%7D&setAttr.photo={y=91.5186%26x=210.501%26width=40.883668%26height=61.4792%26visible=false%26rotation=0%26scaleX=1.0%26scaleY=1.0%26source%3D@Embed%28%27is%28company1/19168388%29%27%29}&setAttr.bleed={visible=false}&setAttr.insertedImagesPlaceholder={visible=false}&setElement.name=%253Ccontent%253E%253Cdiv%2520columnCount%253D%25221%2522%2520columnGap%253D%252218%2522%2520fontFamily%253D%2522Comic%2520Sans%2520MS%2522%2520textAlign%253D%2522left%2522%2520s7%253AcolorName%253D%2522100%2525%2520Black%2522%2520s7%253Acolorspace%253D%2522defined%2522%2520s7%253AcolorValue%253D%2522%2523FF%2522%253E%253Cp%253E%253Cspan%253EName%253C/span%253E%253C/p%253E%253C/div%253E%253C/content%253E&setAttr.name=%7Bheight=17.825466666666667%2526visible=true%2526rotation=0%7D&setElement.date=%253Ccontent%253E%253Cdiv%2520columnCount%253D%25221%2522%2520columnGap%253D%252218%2522%2520fontFamily%253D%2522Comic%2520Sans%2520MS%2522%2520textAlign%253D%2522left%2522%2520s7%253AcolorName%253D%2522100%2525%2520Black%2522%2520s7%253Acolorspace%253D%2522defined%2522%2520s7%253AcolorValue%253D%2522%2523FF%2522%253E%253Cp%253E%253Cspan%253EDate%253C/span%253E%253C/p%253E%253C/div%253E%253C/content%253E&setAttr.date=%7Bheight=17.82646666666667%2526visible=true%2526rotation=0%7D&setElement.announcement=%253Ccontent%253E%253Cdiv%2520columnCount%253D%25221%2522%2520

**Update 3: I now get HTTP 403 forbidden error when I try to browse the URL in a separate window. Any suggestions?**

Comment: cam you include the URL - if it's too long then it's too long, but more likely there is a bug in it somewhere

Comment: What is this "external source"? How is it possible that it generates urls that exceed maximum allowed length? And what exact length you got there?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: We read from XML file where it is stored. The same URL is displayed by another application where in they have used Javascript with POST method. So it works on the other application. I would like to know how I can achive POST within OnLoad.

Comment: @web_bod : There is no bug in URL because it renders in the other application. I don't know if I can post URL here as it is quite long.

Comment: How long is it? And where did you get the idea that it is "too long"? What exception/error are you getting, from what program?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: The total length of URL is around 2047. When I assign the URL to the image control, there is no runtime error but image is not displayed. If I trim the URL until first query string, it displays. I have pasted the actual URL in my original post.

Comment: That URL is *absolutely not* too long. Though I'm going to bet it is invalid, due to lack of proper encoding.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You mean to say the code I have in OnLoad, should display this image as it is. There is no need to achieve using POST, javascript etc??. thanks.

Comment: @Anirudh *No*. That is not what I said, *at all*. I said it is likely *encoded incorrectly*, and I said nothing about "POST, Javascript, etc". (which I don't understand why would be a 'solution' here, anyway)

Comment: "POST" and "Javascript" are not even remotely solutions here. The problem is your URL is mis-encoded somehow. The web browser is fixing that for you when you type it in the address bar, but the server control can't do that for you. (And no; the answer is *not* to "force" it to - it is to figure out how that URL is mis-encoded.

Comment: @AndrewBarber:Thanks for the input. I am about to give up on javascript but other vendor asked me to show about javascript failing. I updated my other question. Please let me know if you get a chance. Sorry for bothering. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the issue by using webservices and getting the url details.