# ASP.NET -> How to POST data to the form such that images are displayed

Tags: asp.net, jquery, post, http-get, imageurl

Scenario : ASP.NET site has a page named ShowDesign.aspx.

ASPX page has lot of controls. I have a DIV tag and I load the images in code behind. DIV is defined something like below in the ASPX.

```
<div id="pImageHolder" runat="server"></div>
```

Below is the code behind that loads images.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    //Loop inside PreviewImages which has lots of images.
    foreach (String imgFile in this.PreviewImages)
    {
        Image pImage = new Image();

        pImage.ImageUrl =  imgFile; //URL length is longer. Do something.

        this.pImageHolder.Controls.Add(pImage);
    }
}
```

**Update : Jun 1,2012 ->** I have updated this question with more clarity as to what I am trying to do.

In OnInit(), I get the URL of the image (in the above loop). Every image will have unique URL.

Since the URL length of every image is longer, it doesn't display. The solution to this issue seems to be POSTING data to the form. The data that needs to be POSTED will be the URL contents.

The URL contains lot of '&' and I need to submit the contents of each '&' to the form. 
Don't know if I need to use AJAX or Jquery here.

I need some help here to achieve the above.

Hope my question is clear. If not, please let me know.

Comment: it's the same question for the 3rd time, setting URL to image control "using javascript with POST" doesn't make sense. Describe more better what you are trying to do. What is that image that you want to display withing image control ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula: I have updated my original posting. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I suspect that length of URL is no the problem, asking you again, does this url works (shows picture) if you paste it in browser address bar ?

Comment: The image is shown in non-IE browsers. IE fails and it is because of url length. In order to get this working, I have to POST the URL using httpwebrequest. Let me know for any other suggestions.

Comment: And you are expecting to get shorter url ?

Answer (score 0):

According to latest comments, this question history and at the end you want post data to another url and get response html. Try this (I snipped your original url from previous question since is really big):

```
  string strangeUrl = "http://example.com/is/m//company1/Rec-Sc-105-QL2?setAttr.safe={visible=false}&setAttr.insertedTextPlaceholder={visible=false}";
  string data = strangeUrl.Substring(strangeUrl.IndexOf("?") + 1);

  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  string result = wc.UploadString("www.example.com/addres-for-post.aspx", data);
```